# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added and state has been saved

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a MainActivity and 4 fragments on it.

One of them is called ReportFragment and when the user reaches the last fragment (FinalFragment), it returns to the ReportFragment which is set as active by the fragmentManager.

Though, it is throwing an `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added and state has been saved` when I put application on background and it returns to the ReportFragment.

It happens when I set arguments to the existing Fragment (ReportFragment).

```
Bundle arguments = newFragment.getArguments();
    if (arguments == null) {
        arguments = new Bundle();
    }
    arguments.putInt("CONTAINER", containerId);
    newFragment.setArguments(arguments);
```

Why it does not happen when app is on foreground?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot call `setArguments()` twice on a Fragment as written in it's java docs:

```
/**
* Supply the construction arguments for this fragment.  This can only
* be called before the fragment has been attached to its activity; that
* is, you should call it immediately after constructing the fragment.  The
* arguments supplied here will be retained across fragment destroy and
* creation.
*/
public void setArguments(Bundle args) {

    if (mIndex >= 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment already active");
    }
    mArguments = args;
}
```

Instead you can do the following to prevent the Exception:

```
if (newFragment.getArguments() == null) {
   Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
   arguments.putInt("CONTAINER", containerId);
} else {
   newFragment.getArguments().putInt("CONTAINER", containerId);
}
```

In order to tell you why this happens when your app goes in background, it's is important to know when you call this peace of code. I assume you call it in a static newInstance method where you reference a static reference of your Fragment (`newFragment`).